# How the Naive Bayes works

Tags: python, scikit-learn, statistics, naivebayes

I already read about the naive bayes that it is a classification technique algorithm and can make predication based on the data you give, but in this example I just cant get it how the output [3,4] came.

Following the example:

```
#assigning predictor and target variables
x= np.array([[-3,7],[1,5], [1,2], [-2,0], [2,3], [-4,0], [-1,1], [1,1], [-2,2], [2,7], [-4,1], [-2,7]])
Y = np.array([3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4]

#Create a Gaussian Classifier
model = GaussianNB()

# Train the model using the training sets 
model.fit(x, y)

#Predict Output 
predicted= model.predict([[1,2],[3,4]])
print predicted

Output: ([3,4])
```

Can anyone explain how in this case [3,4] generated and what does this mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please go through below sample code.

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
import numpy as np

model = GaussianNB()
#assigning predictor and target variables
x= np.array([[-3,7],[1,5], [1,2], [-2,0], [2,3], [-4,0], [-1,1], [1,1], [-2,2], [2,7], [-4,1], [-2,7]])
Y = np.array([3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4])
print x

model.fit(x, Y)

#Predict Output 
predicted= model.predict([[1,2],[35,6], [2,6]])
print predicted
```

output:

```
[3 4 4]
```

Here we got 3 values.
3 corresponds to [1,2], 4 corresponds to [35,6], etc.

So, based on your sample size, you can see that either you get 3 or 4 value. so depending on the test data it gave [3,4] for your test data. Hope this clarifies.

From your code, for example I just take first 3 entries. You can see the chart below. X_1 and X_2 are feature vector(Input) and Y is your output. Based on input and output the algorithm generate one mathematical formula. When you give your test data it uses same formula to generate output (Y).Thats how you got [3,4].

[image]

Comment: how 4 is corrosponding to [35,6]? I dont get this. I think you need to explain more how u got [3,4,4] for each element. and probably what is x, and Y in this case, why does x is small letter while Y is capital letter? what x is responsible for and what y?

Comment: thanks, I think know it makes more sense! thou for [35,6] input we dont have any output training in Y but it predicts it 4.

Comment: to predict value for [35, 6] , it shouldn't necessarily be in training data. You can understand why? If thats the case you can predict only for those which are there in training set and in this case it won;t be called as prediction.

Comment: got it, thnx alot!